# MultiLanguage - Logic error beginner

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am using `WIndows 8`, and `Visual Studio 2012 Metro`. I need to add a `DropDownList` and make the user select languages. When the user selects a particular language i need all the Text values in the label to change to that particular language.

[I followed this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-BXpZyoxHzY)

```
I  R-CLick project added `APPGlobal_Resource` folder
I R-Clicked and added `APPGlobal_Resource` and created a Resource file called rss.resx 
Then i duplicated this file and named it rss.fr.resx
I gave 2 values `String1` and `Hello` and `Bonjour` as values (in both files)
R-Click `dropdownlist` and `edit item`, and `ADD` and then gave `en-US` as `Name` and `value`as  `en-US` (same way i gave `en-fr`)
Then i set the Label property, `Data (Expression)` `Bindable property` to `Text` and `Expression Type` to `Resources`.

I gave the `Class Key` to `Res` and `Resource Key` to `String1`.
```

and i wrote the following code in `Default.aspx.cs`

```
 protected override void InitializeCulture()
        {
            base.InitializeCulture();
            String cult = Request["DropDownList1"];

            if (cult != null)
            {
                Culture = cult;
                UICulture = cult;
            }
        }
```

The drop down displays with `en-US and en-fr` but when i select it nothing changes. How can i resolve this ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but it can help:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
    new System.Globalization.CultureInfo( cult );
```

Comment: In `if (cult != null)` clause

Comment: But I still think that culture 'en-fr' simply not exist

Comment: I don't understand this line `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
    new System.Globalization.CultureInfo( cultInfo );` are you missing a variable (i am a newbie )

Comment: Use `cult` instead of `cultInfo`.

Comment: I changed it to `fr` as you said, but nothing hapence. I don't have a `        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
` So have i done anything wrong ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22931/discussion-between-bob-sponge-and-sharon-hwk)